# windows phone app UI

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, expression-blend

I have developed a windows phone app.When the phone background is set to black,the UI of my app looks good,but if its changed to white,UI becomes very dirty.How can I solve this problem[image: See the image,Black background gives good look to my app,whereas white makes it bad]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to use "black" background you should check out WP ThemeManager by Jeff Wilcox

It's available as a NuGet package "PhoneThemeManager" [More info here](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/)